# Evaluating if statement in python from a string

Tags: python, if-statement, dynamic

I'm working on a project that allows users to define filters to sort data in a csv file. They can create as many or as few filters as they want so I am trying to create an if statement from a string that will get longer as users define more filters.

I have an output for my string variable which is this: row[0]=="6/1/2014 0:00:00"

So for simplicity sake I'll just hard code that into a variable name in the sample code below

The problem is that it doesn't correctly evaluate this if statement. It returns every row of the file.

```
f = open("somefile.csv", "r")
r = csv.reader(f)

statement = 'row[0]=="6/1/2014 0:00:00"'
for row in r:
    if statment:
       print(row)
```

Comment: Of Course it will evaluate to `True` for every iteration, since you are checking against a value that is not `False`...

Comment: How much trust do you have in these users?  In some ways, this looks like a case for `eval`, but if you don't have 100% trust in your users, then `eval` is not safe and you'll need to parse the string yourself (e.g. via `ast`).

Comment: Is there a way I could use that string in the if statement the same way I would do it if I type it out myself?

Comment: there is always a better way to do things than `eval`. might do you some good to create some sort of api for your users that will create filters in a safer manner

Comment: the string is a result of some other code I created to parse through user input so yeah I'll try eval

Comment: Why not dump the CSV into a [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) database -- Then your users can query it using more familiar SQL and you don't need to use `eval` or `ast` to parse the filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the obvious security reasons you will have to take care of, you can use `eval`:

```
if eval(statement):
    print row
```

Comment: [Eval is really dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: Should consider `ast` module instead

Comment: If the users are explicitly trusted (i.e., this is a piece of code that runs on a local machine, and not a web service or the like), then eval() is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yup, better create a high level interface for your users to define filters and then you may interpret the choices into actual python statements. This was just a quick answer to your quick workaround, but doesn't mean this is the way to go.

Comment: What would be another approach that would be safer? what is the ast module?